# Swift 2 Error: Editor placeholder in sourcefile

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: <#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
```

I keep getting the error `editor placeholder in source file`.
I also get the error `Static member 'Subtitle' cannot be used on instance of type 'UITableViewCellStyle'`.

Comment: `<#T##UITableViewCellStyle#>.Subtitle` might be something you should look at.

Comment: I'm saying that that is probably the problematic section.

Comment: and it still says editor placeholder in source file. I saw your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an editor placeholder in your file (the compiler points that out very nicely). Change the erroneous line to this:

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "test")
```